# How to create a netCDF file with python netCDF4?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am learning how to use netCDF4 using Python module in Anaconda. I am trying to append values to two variables I have created `time` and `field`:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

root_grp = Dataset('py_netcdf4.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
root_grp.description = 'Example simulation data'

ndim = 128 # Size of the matrix ndim*ndim
xdimension = 0.75
ydimension = 0.75
# dimensions
root_grp.createDimension('time', None)
root_grp.createDimension('x', ndim)
root_grp.createDimension('y', ndim)

# variables
time = root_grp.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
x = root_grp.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x',))
y = root_grp.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y',))
field = root_grp.createVariable('field', 'f8', ('time', 'x', 'y',))

# data
x_range =  np.linspace(0, xdimension, ndim)
y_range =  np.linspace(0, ydimension, ndim)
x[:] = x_range
y[:] = y_range
for i in range(5):
    time[i] = i*50.0
    field[i,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(x_range), len(y_range)))


root_grp.close
```

But now when I print one of the variables I get that it's empty(!!):

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from netCDF4 import Dataset
>>> root_grp = Dataset('py_netcdf4.nc', 'r', format='NETCDF4')
>>> print root_grp.variables["field"][:,:,:]
[]
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

root_grp = Dataset('py_netcdf4.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
root_grp.description = 'Example simulation data'

ndim = 128 # Size of the matrix ndim*ndim
xdimension = 0.75
ydimension = 0.75
# dimensions
root_grp.createDimension('time', None)
root_grp.createDimension('x', ndim)
root_grp.createDimension('y', ndim)

# variables
time = root_grp.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
x = root_grp.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x',))
y = root_grp.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y',))
field = root_grp.createVariable('field', 'f8', ('time', 'x', 'y',))

# data
x_range =  np.linspace(0, xdimension, ndim)
y_range =  np.linspace(0, ydimension, ndim)
x[:] = x_range
y[:] = y_range
for i in range(5):
    time[i] = i*50.0
    field[i,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(x_range), len(y_range)))


root_grp.close()
```

The only difference is that I call the `close()` method: `root_grp.close()`.

Comment: To avoid mistakes like that (e.g. missing brackets on `close` method), use [the python with statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31819754).